# Is it possible to get access to what's device plays with AVAudioPlayer (or other SDK)?

Tags: ios, audio, avaudioplayer

Rather to explicitly load a song from the library for example such as in:

audioPlayer = [[AVAudioPlayer alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:url error:nil];

Can I get access to what's the device currently is playing?